# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR by http get request angular 15.2

Tags: angular, api, http

```
getDisastersByDate(date: string) {
    if(date == this.getCurrentDate()) {
      // current disasters
      this.url = "https://api.reliefweb.int/v1/disasters?appname=rwint-user-0&profile=full&preset=latest&slim=1&limit=1000";
} else {
...
}

    return this.http.get(this.url, {responseType: "json"});
  }
```

Everything worked fine till I got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcVix.png)

I tried a lot of solutions with browser setttings, but it did not worked for me either.

Comment: it works some times & sometimes it don't. Depends on server disk space.

Comment: Yeah! You are right!